Logloss worse than random guessing with xgboost
I have a binary classification problem that I am currently trying to tackle with xgboost. This is a low signal-to-noise ratio situation dealing with time series. My out of sample AUC is 0.65, which is Ok (better than random guessing which would give 0.5). However, my logloss is extremely high, around 0.68. Looking at this answer "Dumb" log-loss for a binary classifier, considering I have 20% positives, I would expect to have logloss lower than
0.2*log(0.2) + 0.8*np.log(0.8) = 0.5

However, my logloss seems quite terrible, but at the same time, the AUC looks Ok. F1 is also alright, around 0.35 (random classifier that guesses 1 with 20% probability would achieve F1=0.2).
I am mainly confused about how I am getting such high logloss, am I doing something wrong, or am I misunderstanding something? Even if my features are pure noise (which I don't think they are), how is xgboost not able to get a lower logloss?
Note: The AUC I am using and reporting above comes from sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score, and same for all other metrics.

The second paragraph of my answer in the duplicate explains "A model with high discrimination is not necessarily well calibrated. Suppose a logistic regression model predicts probabilities of 0.52 for positives and 0.51 for negatives. This model has an AUC of 1, but the probabilities aren't helpful." So it's completely consistent to have both a high AUC and a high log-loss. If you're asking about something else, please [edit] to clarify.

Yes, I edited the question, but maybe it wasn't clear enough - my emphasis now is on how I am getting logloss worse than a naive guessing model?

You should rewrite your question to focus on that.

Thanks for the feedback, I will do that.

I posted the question here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/651260/extremely-high-logloss-in-binary-classification-problem, but then it got closed because it's marked as duplicate of this one, which is closed? It doesn't make sense, someone please help @Sycorax

This question isn't closed. You can verify it’s not closed because if you scroll up on this page, the title doesn't say "[closed]" and there is no closure banner in a blue box.

Got it, thanks for clarifying.

its hard to say without knowing more.  eg perhaps your training data has a different distribution than your test set.  what is your average prediction in training set/test set? what is the class probability in train/test set?

Well, even in my training set, the logloss is 0.65. Forget about in-sample vs out-of-sample: how is it so bad in-sample?

so what are the average predictions?

A calibration curve (also available in sklearn) might shed some light. The hyperparameters searched/selected could also be useful information.

Log loss is a strictly proper scoring rule, which means that it can be decomposed into measures of calibration (if the predicted probabilities align with the reality of event occurrence frequency) and discrimination (if distinct outcomes are predicted to be different). Brier score has the most famous decomposition, but there is a theorem (I confess to forgetting the citation, perhaps something by Gneiting) that every strictly proper scoring rule can be decomposed this way.
ROCAUC only considers the predictive discrimination. In fact, you can divide all of your predicted probabilities by a million without changing the ROCAUC.
In the extreme, you could have a perfect ROCAUC of one and terrible log loss, due to a lack of calibration despite the perfect discrimination.
As many machine learning models have poor calibration, your results are not extremely surprising.

Thanks, Any insights as to how the logloss ends up so bad though? Leaving aside all other metrics - I set logloss as the objective, and yet the model ends up worse than random guessing. Any suggestions how I can diagnose this further?

@BaronYugovich xgboost's results depend crucially on the learning rate. How are you tuning the model hyperparameters?

I tried some cross validation, and all metaparams have the same problem. Although, I don't change the learning rate, mostly about number of trees and max. depth to prevent overfitting.

"I don't change the learning rate" well, there's your problem.

I see. But per this https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html I don't see the learning rate as a parameter, other than through LearningRateScheduler. Are you saying that's what I must use?

@BaronYugovich Ctrl+F shows that the phrase "learning rate" appears all over the docs for the Python API. For instance, it's in https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier
