Extremely high logloss in binary classification problem
I have a binary classification problem that I am currently trying to tackle with xgboost. This is a low signal-to-noise ratio situation dealing with time series. Per this answer "Dumb" log-loss for a binary classifier, considering I have 20% positives, I would expect to have logloss lower (better) than
0.2*log(0.2) + 0.8*np.log(0.8) = 0.5
However, my logloss seems quite terrible, close to 0.65 even in-sample.
I am confused about how I am getting such high logloss, am I doing something wrong, or am I misunderstanding something? Even if my features are pure noise (which I don't think they are), how is xgboost not able to get a lower logloss?
I would appreciate any guidance, both in a generic modeling sense, as well as specific to xgboost.
